How to parse strings in C++ w/Delimiters?
This has been taking me forever to figure out and i have researched so many different examples, but some seem so convoluted and have extra steps in them for reasons A,B,C..... This is what I need-Let's say you have a string and we will call it string A
String A = "I<Like<Butterscotch<candies<so<much"
So the delimiter of course is '<'
How do I parse this string to take out the delimiters? I then have to make objects of these strings and add them to an array of pointers.
Please see an example below:) Please ignore all the directives at the top. I hate guessing what I need and don't need so I started including every one I need in all files (except for including files within others). I have spent 6+ hours researching parsing and I am getting nowhere, so I am officially done for the night.....
I am also confused by pointers I guess because I thought the line below would be a pointer to take my data from the Student class in my student header file and have it create an Array of Pointers, which I will then fill with objects using the 'add' method below........ but it tells me-Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'Student *' with an rvalue of type 'string *' (aka 'basic_string<char> *').... I feel like I am taking a step forward then hitting a wall and bouncing back 2 steps while trying to learn this material.....
Student* classRosterArray = new string[5];

#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <print>
#include <iomanip>
#include "student.hpp"
using namespace std;

class Roster
{
private:
    // Array of pointers, size = 5-- I thought I was supposed to use a pointer to reference the Student class.... and call the new array which we are adding objects into classRosterArray?
    Student* classRosterArray = new string[5];
    //string* classRosterArray = new string[5]; --Is this what is needed??
    
public:
    void parse(string row);
    void add(string studentId,
             string firstName,
             string lastName,
             string emailAddress,
             int age,
             int daysToComp3Course,
             DegreeProgram degreeProgram);
};


See the 3rd std::getline usage example. This example answers your question.

As a side-note, do not manage classRosterArray yourself. Use std::vector<Student> instead.

I then have to make objects of these strings and add them to an array of pointers. -- You should focus on one question, not several.  I posted an answer to your first question.

Another side note in add pass your strings by const & and stop using using namespace std;


How do I parse this string to take out the delimiters?

To extract each word, use std::getline and std::istringstream:
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string A = "I<Like<Butterscotch<candies<so<much";
    std::istringstream strm(A);
    std::string word;
    while (std::getline(strm, word, '<'))
        std::cout << word << "\n";
}

Output:
I
Like
Butterscotch
candies
so
much

